# (Longitudinal data) Create new variable with last value for each ID

Tags: r, longitudinal

I am working with a longitudinal dataset with ID's, timestamps, and values. I would like to create a new variable for each individual that saves the value for the last timestamp for that individual in each of that individual's rows. For example, if my data looked like this:

```
    ID Time Value
    1  1:20  1
    1  2:43  2
    1  1:56  3
    2  1:10  4
    2  1:05  5
```

I would want to create a new variable Final_value as such:

```
    ID Time Value Final_value
    1  1:20  1    2
    1  2:43  2    2
    1  1:56  3    2
    2  1:10  4    4
    2  1:05  5    4
```

I prefer to use R's built-in methods. Perhaps there is a way to do this using the "ave" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `dplyr`.  Grouped by 'ID', convert the 'Time' to time class with `hm` from `lubridate`, get the index of the max (`which.max`) and subset the 'Value' based on that index

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(Final_value = Value[which.max(as.numeric(hm(Time)))])
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID Time  Value Final_value
#  <int> <chr> <int>       <int>
#1     1 1:20      1           2
#2     1 2:43      2           2
#3     1 1:56      3           2
#4     2 1:10      4           4
#5     2 1:05      5           4
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$Final_value <- with(df1, Value[as.logical(ave(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Time, 
           format = '%H:%M')),
      ID, FUN = function(x) x== max(x)))][ID])
```

Or another option is to `order` the data based on the 'Time' and 'ID', and then get the `last` value with `ave`

```
i1 <- with(df1, order(ID, as.POSIXct(TIme, format = '%H:%M')))
with(df1[i1,], ave(Value, ID, FUN = function(x) x[length(x)]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Time = c("1:20", "2:43", 
"1:56", "1:10", "1:05"), Value = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is the `data.table` way of thinhs

```
library( data.table )
#make your data (dt) a data.table
setDT( dt )
#set Time as a  iTime
dt[, Time := as.ITime( Time )]
#get the value of the max Time, by ID
dt[, Final_value :=  , by = .( ID ) ]
#perform an update join, where you join 
#  the maximum Value by ID on dt itself
dt[ dt[dt[, .I[Time == max(Time)], by = ID]$V1], 
    Final_value := i.Value, 
    on = .(ID)]

#    ID     Time Value Final_value
# 1:  1 01:20:00     1           2
# 2:  1 02:43:00     2           2
# 3:  1 01:56:00     3           2
# 4:  2 01:10:00     4           4
# 5:  2 01:05:00     5           4
```